# '\n' is rendered in react native text component when string is read from file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I render simple text with new lines in Text component:

```
<Text>{'Hello,\n\nWorld'}</Text>
```

And this show two new lines and it's ok.
But if I read string from file and try to render it this is what I got:

```
Hello,\n\nWorld
```

Why `\n` is displayed in text label here.
Only difference is that in second case I read value from file and store it in variable?
How to make text render with new lines and not `\n` character as string?
So what confuses me is that exactly same string hardcoded work fine display new lines but when get it from variable it render \n

Comment: When you read from a file your 'escaped' characters get 'escaped'. So you can either remove the extra 'escaped' characters or just 'escape' the 'escaped escaped' characters.

Comment: I don't understand? Some example? I print string in console and copy that string and hardcode it and it work fine. But when reading it it renders '\n'

Comment: Try str.replace("\\n", "\n") inside <Text>, where str is the string you read from the file.

Comment: Doesn't work. As I said in string it's 'Hello\n\nWorld'

Comment: Faced the exact scenario. At the end i just splitted the string using '\n' and made the new line using <br /> tag between splitted values